# How do i achieve [x if func(x,lst) for x in list] in haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion

Okay so I come from a python background and am new with haskell and doing an assignment. I am done with the question itself but my logic/code looks ugly and wanted to know of ways to improve it. What I want to do is iterate over a list with that list as argument to call another function.

Assuming that I want to achieve the following in haskell.

```
input = [1,2,2,3,3,4,5]
output = [1,4,5] #occurs Once
```

so i want to go from `x->y`

normally how I'd do it would be

```
def checksOnce(input):
  lst = []
  for val in input:
    if occursOnce(val,input):
      lst.append(val)
  print(lst)
```

How do i do that iterating in haskell? I have a function that works fine for occursOnce which takes a value and list and returns a bool just like python.

```
checksOnce :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
checksOnce [] lst = []
checksOnce (x:xs) lst
  | occursOnce x lst = [x] ++ checksOnce xs lst
  | otherwise = checksOnce xs lst
```

and something like `mainFunc lst = checksOnce lst lst` to call the above function.

The above works fine and is sufficient as far as my hw goes, but passing the same argument Once is redundant! How do i go from `checksOnce :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]` to `checksOnce :: [Int] -> [Int]` and use just one list to iterate over like the above python code instead of passing the same list Once to the function?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't your python code (and your haskell code for that matter), put every entry in the result twice?  For example outputting `[2,2,3,3]` instead of `[2,3]`.  Wouldn't it be better to just check if the `x` appears in `xs` exactly once to avoid duplication?

Comment: Please add your `occursTwice` function (both the Python and Haskell versions) to your question.

Comment: I believe your Haskell version should have `checksTwice` to the right of the equals sign in both the last 2 lines, instead of `occursTwice`

Comment: I chose occursTwice just as an example for over here. I just want to know how to iterate over the list and call a function passing each element as well as the list as argument.

Assume it to be occursOnce to make it simpler. Then the first one will result in a result if i check x in xs.

Comment: "passing the same argument twice is redundant" - this is not true, because the first argument of `checksTwice` changes and the second does not. The two arguments serve different purposes, and you do different things with them; it just so happens they have the same value at the top-level call. Another way to write `checksTwice` is `\lst -> filter (flip occursTwice lst) lst`. Why are you compelled to make your Haskell code "like" (i.e. superficially similar to) your Python code?

Comment: Thanks @RobinZigmond for catching that. I wrote that on the fly above for stackoverflow and missed that.

Comment: @user2407038 I agree it doesn't mean that it is redundant. However, passing the same argument twice just doesn't feel right to me internally. The reasoning behind wanting it to be similar is that it will help me grasp haskell better. I wanted to use my own logic to solve the question.

So I am to assume that there is no way to achieve `for x in lst: fun(x,lst)` with just lst as argument easily? If not, that's a bummer. I just wanted to reduce the extra helper function call that i am making.

Comment: @SyedShariqAli The core of the problem is viewing this function call as "extra". Haskell has no iteration, only recursion. Furthermore, a recursive function with a starting condition is implemented by having a helper function to which you pass the initial value. Note that in both Haskell and Python this function can be implemented with code in which `input` syntactically appears exactly twice. You given code in both languages which does this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haskell has list comprehensions, so you can do:

```
\f xs -> [x | x <- xs, f x xs]
```

You can also do this with a filter:

```
\f xs -> filter (\x -> f x xs) xs
```

Comment: Can you explain the code a bit as well? This seems cool. I'll check list comprehensions out. Thanks

Comment: Is there something particular you'd like me to talk about? They are both anonymous functions (lambdas) that take two variables: the predicate, which you called `f`; and the list, which I am calling `xs` in the Haskell tradition.

Comment: @SadisticSardines `[x | x <- lst, func x lst]` is the direct translation of Python's `[x if func(x,lst) for x in list]`. `<-` takes the place of `for...in`, and conditions are written without an `if`.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest, and probably most idiomatic, way to write this function in Haskell would be to use `filter`:

```
checksTwice :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -- you can keep it as [Int] -> [Int] if you like, but this more general type signature is better because the function works on any type that can be compared for equality
checksTwice xs = filter (\x -> occursTwice x xs) xs
```

Or if you prefer (although the gain is debatable), rewriting the lambda in "point-free" style:

```
checksTwice :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
checksTwice xs = filter (flip occursTwice xs) xs
```

(Which is exactly the answer suggested in the comments by @user2407038 - apologies for "stealing" your answer)

Answer (score 1):

Well just like you did in your Python you'd want to have the variable `lst` only visible to the function `checksTwice` and not a parameter.  Haskell throws some people for a loop what with it's lack of looping primitives - the solution is usually a helper function of a higher order function.

```
checksOnce :: [Int] ->  [Int]
checksOnce xs = go xs xs
  where go [] _ = []
        go (x:xs) lst
          | occursOnce x lst = x : go xs lst
          | otherwise = go xs lst
```

But this pattern, including `x` if and only if `f x` is just a filter so...

```
checksOnce x = filter (`occursOnce` lst) xs
```

As @RobinZigmond noted, this still has a bug vs the behavior you desire.